# Gravitational waves cause by photons?

Tags: photons, gravitational-waves

I was reading this question ([Why does Light get caught by Gravity, when both are travelling at the Speed of Light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/526351/156576)) and it brought me to the following:

Can photons create gravitational waves?

My rationale here is:

(1) although photos have no *mass*, they do have *momentum* (and I've always been a bit confused by this - how it works, etc.). It is an acceleration of mass that is required specifically to cause gravitational waves or would an acceleration of photon count as well?

(2) does a change of direction constitute a change of acceleration (eg, a photon on the edge of a gravity well of a black hole)?

(3) if (1) and (2) are both possible, then am I correct in thinking this means a photon does cause a gravitational wave?

Comment: see this https://arxiv.org/abs/2001.10196

Comment: @user6916458: Are you asking whether or not two photons attract each another due to their mutually curved space-time, are you asking whether or not they are able to generate **detectable** gravitational waves, or are you asking something completely different?

Comment: You might be interested in the **Aichelburg-Sexl metric**. The original reference is [On the gravitational field of a massless particle](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00758149).

Comment: @Semoi I'm not concerned about detectability, but whether the effect should excists

Answer (score -1):

**Do two photons interact gravitationally?**

Yes, they do. The simple picture is that photons have energy $E=\hbar \omega$ and that this leads to a mass, $m=E/c^2$. Therefore, two phonons attract each another by curving the space-time. The more complex description uses the energy-momentum tensor of general relativity theory.

**Does photons generate gravitational waves?**

Although photons do disturb space-time, I would **not** call this disturbances a gravitational wave. E.g. the [Ligo project](https://www.ligo.caltech.edu/page/what-are-gw) writes:

> Gravitational waves are 'ripples' in space-time caused by some of the most violent and energetic processes in the Universe. Albert Einstein predicted the existence of gravitational waves in 1916 in his general theory of relativity. Einstein's mathematics showed that massive accelerating objects (such as neutron stars or black holes orbiting each other) would disrupt space-time in such a way that 'waves' of undulating space-time would propagate in all directions away from the source.

Since photons are not in this line of thought it seams to be wrong to call their gravitational effect a gravitational wave.

Comment: I'm not sure I buy this. Are you sure there aren't solutions to the Maxwell-Einstein equations containing gravitational waves? I don't know, but I guess this is the question at hand.

Comment: If this is the question, I completely misunderstood it. @user6916458 could you please clarify your question.